# Duplicated Number Perfect Squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For which numbers $N$ is the number $10^k \cdot N + N$, where $k$ is $N$'s length, a perfect square?

Comment: with length you mean the length of the digits?

Comment: I guess because he wrote as title Duplicated Number.

Comment: I think this is an useful rewording of this question: for which $k$ is there an $N$ such that $10^k\cdot N+N$ is a perfect square and $[log_{10}]=k-1$?

Comment: I've got good luck and I've noticed, that the rest class of 10 generates the multiplicative group of the reduced rest classes modulo 49. So I made an example: $$428571428571428571429^2= 183673469387755102041\,183673469387755102041$$

Comment: Using WolframAlpha I found the least example: $$36363636364^2=13223140496\,13223140496$$

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, just a lead.

First of all, forget that $k$ is the length of $N$ in decimal. Just fix $k$ and look for integer solutions to $10^kx + x=y^2$.

A number is square if and only if the power of every prime in its factorization is even. Now factor $10^kx+x$ as $x(10^k+1)$ and it becomes apparent that the problem here is determining the prime factorization of $10^k+1$. For example, with $k=3$, $10^k+1=1001=7\cdot11\cdot13$, so $x(10^k+1)$ is square iff the powers of $7$, $11$ and $13$ in $x$ are all odd, in other words, $x$ must be of the form $7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot t^2$, where $t$ is an integer. More generally, if $p_1, ... p_n$ are the prime factors of odd exponent in $10^k+1$, $x$ must be of the form $p_1...p_nt^2$, where $t$ is an integer.

Once the general case is worked out, we can use it to find solutions $x$ such that the length of $x$ in decimal is $k$. Let $s=p_1...p_n$ as above. Then $x$ is a solution iff $x$ is of the form $st^2$, $t\in\mathbb Z$. Note that by construction, $s$ divides $10^k+1$ and $\frac{10^k+1}{s}$ is square, say equal to $a^2$, that is $10^k+1=sa^2$, so $sa^2$ is of length $k+1$. Thus if there are any solutions $x=st^2$ of length $k$, $t$ must be one of the numbers between $1$ and $a-1$ (inclusive).

Thus the problem can be reformulated quite simply as: what is the largest square dividing $10^k+1$? This largest square is what we called $a^2$ in the last paragraph.